# Is this statement true?(product and quotient of the groups and rings)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Is this statement true?

**-statement-**

**Let $A  \simeq A_1 \times A_2$ with $B \lhd A$ (A is a either a ring or a group)**

**then, $A/B \simeq (A_1/B) \times (A_2 / B)$**

ex) When the ring case

Let the Ring $R$ s.t. $R \simeq R_1 \times R_2$ with its ideal I ($I \lhd R$)

Then the $R/I \simeq (R_1/I) \times (R_2 / I)$

On the other case when the group

For the group $G$ s.t. $G \simeq G_1 \times G_2$ with its normal subgroup N ($N \lhd G$)

Then the $G/N \simeq (G_1/N) \times (G_2 / N)$

---

I tried to prove this by taking the mappings like the below.

When the ring case $(R, +, \bullet)$

$\phi_R$ :  $R \to (R_1/I) \times (R_2 / I)$ by  $\phi_R(r) = (r_1 + I, r_2 + I)$ for $r (\in R) \simeq r_1  \times r_2$

With the same method for group, $(G, \bullet)$

$\phi_G$ :  $G \to (G_1/N) \times (G_2 / N)$ by  $\phi_G(g) = (g_1 \bullet N, g_2 \bullet N)$ for $g (\in G) \simeq g_1  \times g_2$

As far as I knew, kernel of the each mappings are $I$ and $N$.
So all we need to do check the well-defined, homomorphism, surjectivity.

Then my conclusion is the statement is true.

But still I don't have any confidence that my knowledge and proof is right or not. What do you think about that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a quotient group $G/N$ to be defined, $N$ must be a normal subgroup of $G$.
Similarly, for a quotient ring $R/I$ to be defined, $I$ must be an ideal of $R$.

For $A\cong A_1 \times A_2$ with $B \lhd A$, it is not necessarily that $B\lhd A_1$ and $B\lhd A_2$.

For example, take $A=\langle x \rangle \times \langle y \rangle$, $B=A, A_1=\langle x \rangle, A_2=\langle y \rangle$.
In this case, $B\lhd A$ but $B \not\lhd A_1$ and $B\not\lhd A_2$.
So $A_1/B$ and $A_2/B$ are not defined and hence $A/B\cong A_1/B\times A_2/B$ is not true.

However, there is a result that is similar, that is, if $B=B_1\times B_2$ where $B_1\lhd A_1$ and $B_2\lhd A_2$, then $$A/B\cong A_1/B_1\times A_2/B_2$$

Comment: If the $B \lhd A_1$ and $B \lhd A_2$ then Is the above statement is true? (I.e. $A/B \simeq A_1/B \times A_2/B$)

Comment: @se-hyuckyang Still not true. Take finite group $A$ as example. Then you will have $$|A|/|B|=|A_1||A_2|/|B|^2=|A|/|B|^2$$ which is not true in general

Comment: Ah. Thanks, But There are someone who claim the $\mathbb{Z}_{15}[x]/<3x^2 + 5x> \simeq (\mathbb{Z}_{3}[x]/<5x>) \times (\mathbb{Z}_{5}[x]/<3x^2>)$ for the ring $\mathbb{Z}_{15}[x]$ because of the  $\langle 3x^2 + 5x \rangle  = \langle 5x \rangle \lhd   \mathbb{Z}_3[x]$ etc. If so when we limit the consideration only for the $mathbb{Z}_n$ unity case, Is the statement true? If not, Why does it true?

Comment: @se-hyuckyang Refer the last result I gave in the answer. Since $\langle 5x \rangle \lhd Z_3[x]$ and $\langle 3x^2 \rangle  \lhd Z_5[x]$, try to verify that 
 the result can be applied.