# What is the order of this quotient ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Here is the final exam question in the last year semester that I've not solved.

Find the order of the $\mathbb{Z}_{10} [x] / \langle 5x^2 + 2x + 1 \rangle$

How Could I solve it?

---

Intuitive solution(my attempt)

Since $\mathbb{Z_{10}}[x] \simeq \mathbb{Z_2}[x] \times \mathbb{Z_5}[x]$

Then, $\mathbb{Z_{10}}[x] /\langle 5x^2 + 2x + 1 \rangle  \simeq (\mathbb{Z_2}[x] / \langle 5x^2 + 2x + 1 \rangle) \times (\mathbb{Z_5}[x] / \langle 5x^2 + 2x + 1 \rangle$)

$\simeq $ $(\mathbb{Z_2}[x] / \langle x^2 + 1 \rangle) \times (\mathbb{Z_5}[x] / \langle 2x + 1 \rangle$)

Hence the order would be $20$

Sadly It might be false solution based on the my question" [Is this statement true?(product and quotient of the groups and rings)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3504663/is-this-statement-trueproduct-and-quotient-of-the-groups-and-rings/3504699?noredirect=1#comment7208839_3504699)"

Based on the above link, It looks like my solution is incorrect and wrong.

What is correct and fast solving method?

Any help would be appreciated.

The answer I remembered) $20$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is correct. In general, if $A=A_1\times A_2$ is a ring and $I\subset A$ is an ideal, then $I=I_1\times I_2$ with $I_i$ ideal of $A_i$, and $A/I\simeq A_1/I_1\times A_2/I_2$.

The difference with the link you provide is that it is not true that $A/I\simeq A_1/I\times A_2/I$ (mostly because in general it does not make sense).

Comment: To claim for  the $A/I \simeq A_1 / I_1 \times A_2 / I_2$, Does it have to need more condition that $A$ is a ring with unit?